# Have to run function 2 times for setting value to state in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Code:-[image]

```
const [TimeStampsFromFile, setTimeStampsFromFile] = useState([])
const FilePicker = async () => {
        var RNFS = require('react-native-fs')
        // Pick a single file
        try {
            const res = await DocumentPicker.pick({
                type: [DocumentPicker.types.plainText],
            })
            const filepath =
                RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + '/' + 'TimeStamps' + '/' + res.name
            const file = await RNFS.readFile(filepath)

            setTimeStampsFromFile(await file.split('\n'))
            console.log('file data' + TimeStampsFromFile)
        } catch (err) {
            if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
                // User cancelled the picker, exit any dialogs or menus and move on
            } else {
                throw err
            }
        }
    }
```

this function runs on pressing a button in my react native app:-

On pressing the first time, it needs to return value but it simply returns nothing. But on pressing the second time it returns the value. (Why is that??) or Am I making some mistakes in code??

The same thing is also happing with my other button too.

I found this answer : - [hooks not set state at first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61324764/hooks-not-set-state-at-first-time) but not able to  get solution of my problem (if you can help from this answer)

Comment: You mean that console.log shows `TimeStampsFromFile` as empty correct?

Comment: yes, only the first time..And second time it shows value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TimeStampsFromFile` is empty the first time you log it because `setTimeStampsFromFile` is async. If you want to log `TimeStampsFromFile` when value will be updated you could use `useEffect` hook like:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(TimeStampsFromFile);
}, [TimeStampsFromFile]);
```

In this way, every time `TimeStampsFromFile` changes his value, useEffect will be called and log will show current value.

If you need to get the value of the `TimeStampsFromFile` from `FilePicker` function, is not necessary to get this value from `TimeStampsFromFile`. You could do something like:

```
...
const splitFile = await file.split('\n');
setTimeStampsFromFile(splitFile)
console.log('file data' + splitFile)
...
```

Comment: I need this `TimeStampsFromFile`  by setTimeStampsFromFile(splitFile) for my other function.Btw thanks for help,problem solved by using useEffect.